# Confused: Pointers and character arrays in C

Tags: c, pointers, strtok, character-arrays

I'm new to C and trying to split a character array (which I receive from a Serial Port in Ardunio). I looked up some tutorials and came up with this. Help me debug it please.

```
char action[10];
unsigned long duration;

void split(char input[20])
{
 char *param, *ptr;

 param = strtok_r(input, "#", &ptr);
 action = *param;                      // Need help with this line

 param = strtok_r(NULL, "!", &ptr);
 duration = (unsigned long) *param;    // Need help with this line
}
```

From what I understand, strtok_r returns a pointer to the character right after the delimiter(#). So if I wanted action[] to be a subset character array of input[] till the delimiter, what should I do?

Edit:
Input is something like this: "left#1000!"

Comment: Array is special and cannot be "assigned" with `=` operator except for declaration. You need pointer here `char* action`. And you need to turn character to number first (with `strtoul` in this case) to get the duration in `unsigned long`.

Comment: Can you please post an example of your source  character string? Is it like `paramparamparamparam#duration.NNN`?

Comment: If your input uses `!` as the termination mark, add it to the list of separators: `"#!"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your first token is a string, and the second token is a long. You can use [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) to copy `param` into `action`, and then [`strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) to parse an `unsigned long` to `duration`.

```
param = strtok_r(input, "#!", &ptr);
strncpy(action, param, sizeof(action));
// Force zero termination
action[sizeof(action)-1] = '\0';

param = strtok_r(NULL, "#!", ptr);
duration = strtoul(param, &param, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. What I don't understand is this: param here is a pointer. So how does strncpy use it as a parameter?

Comment: @ask, since arrays decay into pointers, and pointers can point to a block of allocated memory, `strncpy` doesn't assume its input to be arrays, but it assumes them to be pointers. It just reads from where they point to onwards until it sees a NUL (or writes to where they point to onwards until the other string ends). You should learn more on functions, arrays and pointers, preferably from a book.

Comment: Thanks. I mostly use  Java, so I only have a rudimentary knowledge of fundamental concepts in C like pointers. Will definitely look it up.

Comment: @downvoter Would you mind providing at least a cursory explanation of why you downvoted an answer that has been accepted?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize `action = *param`.

You need to use

```
memcpy(action, param, strlen(param))
```

and

```
duration = (unsigned long) atoi(param)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use strcpy() and necessary casting in order to assign strings(or char arrays) in C.

Visit http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy

This function will care for membervise assignment between strings. To do it manually you must use loops and assign each array member seperately.

Comment: I'd advise against the use of `strcpy` regardless of the circumstances.

Comment: New in C... I think strcpy is OK for now.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should work in plain C (comments added). You could use a C `struct` to collect values. `Struct`s may be returned from functions like simple data types (as is shown). You could use that as a start for your own program.

**Edit:** Such programs don't need the `strXYZ(..)` functions (useful if you may have `'\0'`-bytes in your incoming data).

```
...

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 typedef struct {
    char action[10];  unsigned long duration;
 } Result;


 Result split(char *input, char delim)
{
 Result result = {'\0', 0};                   // initialize result by zeros
 char *p = (char*)memchr(input, delim, sizeof(result.action)-1); 
 if(p != NULL) {                              // if delimiter found in input 
    memcpy(result.action, input, p-input);    // copy text till delimiter
    result.duration = strtoul(p+1, NULL, 10); // convert number after delimiter
 }
 return result;                               // return values
}

 int main(char argc, const char*argv[])
{
 char input[20] = "left#1000!";

 Result result = split(input, '#');
 printf("action: %s, duration %u\n", result.action, result.duration);

 return 0;
}

...
```

Regards

rbo